# How to use search value contain in array field using eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm working on laravel array serialize. Below is serialize in controller.

```
public function CreateSave(CreateTestTopicRequest $request){
    ...code..
    $testtopic->class_room_id = $request->classroom;
    $testtopic->roomno = serialize($request->roomno);
    ...code..
}
```

Then, roomno will be saved to database like.

```
a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}
```

I would like to get result. For example `class_room_id = 1` and `roomno` only contain in roomno array. I may use command to get all as below.

```
$testtopics = TestTopic::where('class_room_id',1)->get();
```

But, I do not know to get record only class_room_id = 1 and roomno contain in array. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like search in json fields

```php
TestTopic::where('class_room_id',1)->where('roomno', 'like', '%"id": 1%')->first()
```

Answer (score 0):

When checking for an array of values the `whereIn` method can be used:

```
$roomno = 'a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}';

$testtopics = TestTopic::where('class_room_id',1)
                    ->whereIn('roomno', unserialize($roomno))
                    ->get();
```

Multiple where statements can be combined by passing an array:

```
$roomno = 'a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}';

$users = TestTopic::where([
    ['class_room_id', '=', '1'],
    ['roomno', '=', $roomno],
])->get();
```

Comment: Dear MaartenDev. Sorry for unclarify question I meant, I would like find class_room_id = 1 and roomno = 2. But roomno is stored as serialized array. E.g.  $testtopics = TestTopic::where('class_room_id',1)->whereIn('roomno', 2)->get(); . This is wrong because 'roomno' is not array.

Comment: I don't really understand what type of data you are trying to store. The serialized object is an array. Do you want to use all values of the array? Or do you want multiple where checks? @joenpcnpcsolution

Comment: Dear MaartenDev, I have one row with two clumns data. first column name=class_room_id (integer) and the second is roomno (store serialized data). I would like to find class_room_id = 1 and roomno = 2. If roomno array is 1 ,2. Then, result found but if I'm looking for class_room_id = 1 and roomno = 3. Then I will get null instead.

Comment: So you want to search though the array values in the roomno column? But if the array only contains 1 and 2, why would it return values for 3? @joenpcnpcsolution

Comment: Dear MaartenDev, Yes search contain. If 3 then return NULL.